# Button dropdown menus appearing behind other buttons if filter is active

Tags: html, css

Depding on whether a `button: hover` filter is active or not, my dropdown menus appear behind other buttons:

[image]
[image]

I'd like to have buttons become a bit brighter as the user hovers over them, so I used:

```
button:hover {
  filter: brightness(105%);
}
```

Why does the filter affect where the dropdown menus are rendered?

```css
button {
  border: none;
  color: #444;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f3f5;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #d8dadc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1 ! important;
}

button:hover {
  /*filter: brightness(105%);*/
}
```

```html
<button class="dropdown">
  Test
  <span class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">ABC</a>
    <a href="#">123</a>
  </span>
</button>
<button class="dropdown">
  Test
  <span class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">ABC</a>
    <a href="#">123</a>
  </span>
</button>
<br>
<button class="dropdown">
  Test 123
  <span class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">ABC</a>
    <a href="#">123</a>
  </span>
</button>
```

and a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nf4k7m31/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG filter in Firefox breaks z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605772/svg-filter-in-firefox-breaks-z-index)

Comment: @LS_ Thanks for the link, I actually tried playing around with putting z-indices at several places, but I never got it to work. Maybe I haven't found the correct place yet?

Comment: Anything other than none in the filter property creates a new stacking order. So you need to add one more line of CSS(z-index:1;) while hovering on button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your example by setting a higher value for `z-index` on the hovered button. Updated example:

```css
button {
  border: none;
  color: #444;
  padding: 15px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f3f5;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #d8dadc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1 ! important;
}

button:hover {
  filter: brightness(105%);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<button class="dropdown">
  Test
  <span class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">ABC</a>
    <a href="#">123</a>
  </span>
</button>
<button class="dropdown">
  Test
  <span class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">ABC</a>
    <a href="#">123</a>
  </span>
</button>
<br>
<button class="dropdown">
  Test 123
  <span class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">ABC</a>
    <a href="#">123</a>
  </span>
</button>
```